# Why does parameter binding work differently when there is an argument in the route template, e.g. /route/{id}?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've found what seems to be an inconsistent behavior in ASP.NET Web API. Say I have the following controller:

```
public class FooController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("foo")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFoo([FromUri]Bar request)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("foo/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFoo(int id, [FromUri]Bar request)
    {
    }
}
```

If I send a GET request to `/foo`, with no query string parameters, the first method will be executed and its `request` argument will be null - which makes sense. But that's not what happens when I send a request to `foo/1`. In this case, I'd expect only the `id` parameter to be filled with `1`, but it turns out that both arguments are initialized.

Why is that so? If that's by design, what could I do in order to "normalize" that behavior, i.e., make the `request` parameter in both methods to be either null or initialized?

Comment: Which version of Web API are you using? Can you share what is the version of your `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package...There is currently a known issue here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1944, but the issue mentioned here and what you are observing is different...do you see `request` being initialized when the request is `/foo`?

Comment: @KiranChalla I'm using v2.1 (`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` 5.1.2). No, I don't. When I send a request to `/foo`, without any querystring, `request` is null. That's precisely what is reported in the issue you've mentioned (I didn't know it only affects attribute routing, though). But, as I said above, the same isn't true if I send a request to `/foo/1`. If that's a bug, I can move this question to CodePlex, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for checking...looks like the issue you are seeing is probably related to the one in codeplex...if you are looking for consistency, then probably you can take a look at the workaround that i have posted in the comment of the codeplex issue...sure, you can probably add the scenario of `/foo/1` to the above codeplex issue...

Comment: @KiranChalla Thanks for your suggestion. I was already working on a solution very similar to your workaround - I'm glad to see I'm on the right track. :)